# Hilt - Missing binding on CoroutineDispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm refactoring my app with **Hilt** as dependency injection manager.
I have a constructor injectable class, with two parameters in the constructor. One of the parameters is a `CoroutineDispatcher`.

```kotlin
class SubscriptionsLocalDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val subscriptionsDao: SubscriptionsDao,
    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : SubscriptionsDataSource {

}
```

When I try to build the app I get a missing binding error, as below:

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
> public abstract static class ApplicationC implements ApplicationComponent,
> ^
> kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher is injected at
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.data.subscriptions.local.SubscriptionsLocalDataSource(…, dispatcher)
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.data.subscriptions.local.SubscriptionsLocalDataSource is injected at
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.data.subscriptions.SubscriptionsRepositoryImpl(localDataSource, …)
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.data.subscriptions.SubscriptionsRepositoryImpl is injected at
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.di.SubscriptionsModule.bindSubscriptionsRepository(subscriptionsRepositoryImpl)
> javax.inject.Provider<com.anagramma.babacodashboard.data.subscriptions.SubscriptionsRepository> is injected at
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.ui.orders.subscriptions.SubscriptionsViewModel_AssistedFactory(repository, …)
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.ui.orders.subscriptions.SubscriptionsViewModel_AssistedFactory is injected at
> com.anagramma.babacodashboard.ui.orders.subscriptions.SubscriptionsViewModel_HiltModule.bind(factory)
> java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> is injected at
> androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule.provideFactory(…, viewModelFactories)
> @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory java.util.Set<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory> is requested at
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.ActivityEntryPoint.getActivityViewModelFactory() [com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ApplicationC → com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC]
> The following other entry points also depend on it:
> dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultViewModelFactories.FragmentEntryPoint.getFragmentViewModelFactory() [com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ApplicationC → com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC → com.anagramma.babacodashboard.BabacoDashboardApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC]

Am I missing some annotation on CoroutineDispatcher?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know if it's the best way but I just solved by creating a `DispatcherModule` by following [this guide](https://www.valueof.io/blog/injecting-coroutines-dispatchers-with-dagger)

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DispatcherModule {
    @IoDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesIoDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
}

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class IoDispatcher
```

Then I refactored my original class to use IoDispatcher annotation:

```kotlin
class SubscriptionsLocalDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val subscriptionsDao: SubscriptionsDao,
    @IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
) : SubscriptionsDataSource {


}
```