# Dagger Hilt - Missing Binding for CoroutineDispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'll start off with the caveat that I have read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63847790/hilt-missing-binding-on-coroutinedispatcher), however it doesn't explain my situation just to avoid the duplicate question posts.

I am creating a basic app to get to grips with Hilt.

I am developing with MVVM, viewmodel, usecase, repository. I have structured my hilt modules as follows
`CoroutineModule`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
object CoroutineModule {

    @DefaultDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun provideDefaultDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default

    @IoDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun provideIODispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    @MainDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun provideMainDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main

    @MainImmediateDispatcher
    @Provides
    fun providesMainImmediateDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main.immediate
}
```

`CoroutineQualifiers.kt`

```
import javax.inject.Qualifier

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class DefaultDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class IoDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainDispatcher

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
@Qualifier
annotation class MainImmediateDispatcher
```

`RepositoryModule`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideWeatherRepository(weatherService: WeatherService, defaultDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) =
        WeatherRepository(weatherService, defaultDispatcher)
}
```

`UseCaseModule`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object UseCaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideGetWeatherUseCase(repository: WeatherRepository, mapper: WeatherForecastMapper) =
        GetWeatherForecastUseCase(repository, mapper)
}
```

`Weather Respository Constructor`

```
class WeatherRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val weatherService: WeatherService,
    @IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
)
```

When I build the app I get the error below.  I am sure there is a very simple error I'm not seeing.  If someone could point me towards it I'd appreciate it!

```
[Dagger/MissingBinding] kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements WeatherApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher is injected at
          com.gary.weather.di.RepositoryModule.provideWeatherRepository(…, defaultDispatcher)
      com.gary.weather.data.repositories.WeatherRepository is injected at
          com.gary.weather.di.UseCaseModule.provideGetWeatherUseCase(repository, …)
      com.gary.weather.features.weathersummary.domain.usecases.GetWeatherForecastUseCase is injected at
          com.gary.weather.features.weathersummary.view.WeatherSummaryViewModel(getWeatherForecastUseCase)
      com.gary.weather.features.weathersummary.view.WeatherSummaryViewModel is injected at
          com.gary.weather.features.weathersummary.view.WeatherSummaryViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.gary.weather.WeatherApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.gary.weather.WeatherApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.gary.weather.WeatherApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

Comment: By a quick look, you are trying to inject something that has lower scope to higher scope - you can inject singleton scope in view model scope but not the other way around.

Comment: @TheLibrarian thanks for the input.  So I've changed the scope on the `CoroutineModule` to `SingletonComponent` but I'm getting the same error.. is that what you were referring to?

Comment: What @TheLibrarian says is true.  In addition you are manually creating your repository in a module (as the error states) - this fails as your provide function doesn't include a `Qualifier` for the dispatcher, but more than that is not necessary to manually create the repository - you have already annotated the class constructor with `@Inject` exposing it to dagger, remove the repository module completely and annotate your repository class with `@Singleton` - to have the same scope as the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what CoroutineDispatcher you want to inject there. It's trying to find something that provides unqualified `CoroutineDispatcher`.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object RepositoryModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideWeatherRepository(
        weatherService: WeatherService, 
        @IoDispatcher ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ) = WeatherRepository(weatherService, ioDispatcher)
}
```

Also as mentioned, if you want module to provide it, remove the `@Inject` from the constructor of the `WeatherRepository`